# Elasticsearch Get The Highest Score From Groups Of Fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am doing a name query on a document that has multiple fields where the name could appear. In many cases, the name is the same across each document node. However, in some cases, it may be different. I would like to score my query on the highest matching field/node.

So assuming I had the following documents indexed.

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  {"object1": {"name" : 'Todd Hughes'}},
  {"object2": {"name" : 'Todd Hughes'}},
  {"object3": {"name" : 'Todd Hughes'}}
}

{
  "id" : 2,
  {"object1": {"name" : 'Todd Hunt'}},
  {"object2": {"name" : 'Todd Hunt'}},
  {"object3": {"name" : 'Ken Collins'}}
}

{
  "id" : 3,
  {"object1": {"name" : 'Todd Huddle'}},
  {"object2": {"name" : 'Todd Huddle'}},
  {"object3": {"name" : 'Todd Huddle'}}
}
```

I would like to be able to search for "Todd Hunt" and get the second record with the "id" of 2 first. My problem is that these fields are indexed with ngrams and the other documents, #1 and #3 partially match and the sum of each object node/fields are added together. So this does not work for me.

```
"bool" : {
  "should" : [
    {:field : {"object1.name" : "Todd Hunt"}},
    {:field : {"object2.name" : "Todd Hunt"}},
    {:field : {"object3.name" : "Todd Hunt"}}
  ],
  "minimum_number_should_match" : 1
}
```

I have tried reading up on custom scoring and ranking and my head is just spinning. Any ideas on how to structure a query so that the highest ranks of each object1, object2 or object 3 is the final score?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Dis Max query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/dis-max-query/)

> A query that generates the union of documents produced by its subqueries, and that **scores each document with the maximum score for that document as produced by any subquery**, plus a tie breaking increment for any additional matching subqueries

Considering that each **subquery** would be a query for a distinct field, you'd get the desired behavior.

You can optionally use a tie breaker to "give more score" to documents that have matches in more than one field.

Comment: Thanks I ended up finding that last night. Here is what my query ended up looking like. https://gist.github.com/metaskills/5501600